# How do I set the value of HtmlOutputTag in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to dynamically create controls in my bean. I am using JSF 2.0

```
HtmlOutputTag objHtmlOutputTag = new HtmlOutputTag();
```

Now which property of `HtmlOutputTag` should I set to set the content of `HtmlOutputTag`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `HtmlOutputTag` represents a tag, not a component. Rather use `HtmlOutputText`. Then, you can just set the `value` property, exactly as you would do in a real component in the JSF page. If you need it to be a `ValueExpression` rather than a raw `value`, then you need to create it using [`ExpressionFactory#createValueExpression()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#createValueExpression%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29). Here's a kickoff example:

```
HtmlOutputText text = new HtmlOutputText();
text.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{bean.property}", String.class));
```

where the convenience method `createValueExpression()` here look like:

```
private static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression, Class<?> valueType) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
        .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), valueExpression, valueType);
}
```

hide it far away in some utility class so that you don't need to repeat all that code again and again ;) The `valueType` argument obviously should represent the actual type of the property.

The final result in the JSF page should then look like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.property}" />
```

That said, depending on the functional requirement, there may indeed be better and cleaner ways to solve the functional requirement. If you want, you can elaborate a bit more about it so that we can if necessary suggest better ways.

Comment: I know it's old, but if you need this and you are implementing Omnifaces (thanks @BalusC for that library), you could use Components class http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components

Answer (score 1):

As [usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295856/dynamically-add-the-component-in-jsf/2295870#2295870), my advice would be to not add/remove component dynamically. Solve your problem another way:

- **Toggle** visibility of components
- Rebind the **data** belonging to a component

Adding/removing component dynamically is always a source of trouble and chances are that you can do it another way much simpler.

The `outputText` component is easy to use:

```
<h:outputText value="#{BackingBean.myProperty}"/>
```

And you define a getter/setter for `myProperty` in your backing bean. If you really want to do it programmatically (which I discourage unless you have strong arguments), here is an [example](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-jan/o16jsf.html) with a dynamic table.

Comment: Actually i am primefaces AccordionPanel. It does not allow me to bind items directly. So i am manually creating "RSSFeeds" object and adding to accordion to show news on my webpage