# How to create ValueExpression of List type?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, el

How to create JSF EL `javax.el.ValueExpression` of type `java.util.List`?

I'm setting programmatically in Java code PrimeFaces DataTable sort:

```
  DataTable userTable = (DataTable) ComponentLookup.getUIComponent("userTable");
  userTable.setValueExpression("sortBy", 
  createValueExpression("#{user.name}", String.class));
```

where `createValueExpression` is taken from [BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440304/531954):

```
private static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression, 
                                                     Class<?> valueType) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
        .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), 
                               valueExpression, valueType);
}
```

However, when I set `sortMode` to `multiple`, `sortBy` argument is expected to be a `java.util.List` instance.

How can I create EL ValueExpression that would be representing a list?

Comment: how about using Object.class instead of String.class? (just thinking, not sure)

Comment: Have you tried sending `List.class`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that causes IllegalArgumentException, because String is not a List, obviously some special syntax or another way of instantiating a ValueExpression is needed.