# PrimeFaces datatable default sortBy from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a data table with a POJO object:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="object" sortBy="#{object.name}" sortOrder="DESCENDING">
```

`object` has fields `id`, `name`, `date`, `size` for example. I am able to set default sort field using xhtml, but I want set it from backing bean.

I am able to parse column `id` when user creates sort request for example `name`.

```
public void sortEventListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent actionEvent) {
    String id = ((SortEvent) actionEvent).getSortColumn().getColumnKey();
    String[] idPath = id.split(":");
    sortBy = idPath[idPath.length - 1];
    sortOrder = ((SortEvent) actionEvent).isAscending();
}
```

My task detects which column user wants to sort and persists it to db. After reload the data table should be sorted by this column.

When I set

```
sortBy="#{bean.sortBy}" // sortBy = name
```

it's not working and data table is not sorted after rendering the page.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If you bind your data table to a `org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable` object in your bean **or** find the table component in your bean, you can use the table object to set the `sortBy` value expression programmatically.

To get an idea how PrimeFaces is handling sorting, you can have a look at the [source code at GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/feature/SortFeature.java#L86).

When you have the sort column, you can easily get the sort value expression. So, in your listener you could use something like:

```
UIColumn sortColumn = sortEvent.getSortColumn();
ValueExpression sortByVE = sortColumn.getValueExpression("sortBy");
```

By the way, you can replace the parameter type `AjaxBehaviorEvent` with `SortEvent` in your sort listener method.

Now, store the `sortByVE` expression, and set it as the `sortBy` value expression of the bound table when needed:

```
dataTable.setValueExpression("sortBy", sortByVE);
```

If you want to create the value expression from scratch, use something like:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExpressionFactory ef = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(context.getELContext(),
                                              "#{object.name}",
                                              Object.class);
dataTable.setValueExpression("sortBy", ve);
```

In this example `"#{object.name}"` is fixed. You should construct it based on the value you get from your sort listener.

If you want to find your table in your bean, [OmniFaces Components](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components) might be helpful. It also offers a [shortcut method to create value expressions](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Components.java#L1210).

See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [Programmatically getting UIComponents of a JSF view in bean's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509270/programmatically-getting-uicomponents-of-a-jsf-view-in-beans-constructor)
- [How do I set the value of HtmlOutputTag in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439594/how-do-i-set-the-value-of-htmloutputtag-in-jsf)