# Sort column in DataTable via bean by column ID in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Is possible to set default sort column on specific datatable in bean? I'm using dynamic datatables and I can't do this in xhtml file. I need to get this column name (ex. tab:tabDataList:j_idt39:1 ) from database and when I open this page, this column should be selected.

[image]

I tried to use everything ex.

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(tableId);

org.primefaces.component.api.UIColumn uiColumn = dataTable.findColumn(this.sortBy);
            dataTable.setSortColumn(uiColumn);
            dataTable.setSortField(this.sortBy);
            dataTable.setSortOrder(this.sortColumnOrder);

            ValueExpression columnSortByVE = uiColumn.getValueExpression("sortBy");
            dataTable.setDefaultSortByVE(columnSortByVE);
```

Comment: Maybe this article can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955667/primefaces-datatable-default-sortby-from-backing-bean

Comment: Unfortunately no, because in this case, there are using sort listener with SortEvent. In my case, I must to load this settings without any user interraction :(