# Dynamic page with JSF

Tags: forms, jsf

I need to make dynamic web-page/form in JSF. Dynamic: In runtime I get the number of input fields Ill have together with buttons. I'll try to demonstrate you what I need to make.

*inputField1 inputField2 inputField3* **BUTTON1**

inputField4 inputField5 **BUTTON2**

inputField6 inputFiled7 inputField8 inputField9 **BUTTON3**

I hope you understand me what I want to make. So I when I click on some of the buttons I have to collect the data from the input fields and do something with the data.
If I click BUTTON1 I collect data from inputField1 inputField2 inputField3
BUTTON2 inputField4 inputField5, etc.

Probably I should create the input fields programmatically and group them in forms.

Any idea how to do it?
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

As usual (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295856/dynamically-add-the-component-in-jsf/2295870#2295870) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439594/how-do-i-set-the-value-of-htmloutputtag-in-jsf/2439874#2439874)), my advice would be to not add/remove component dynamically. Solve your problem another way:

- Toggle **visibility** of components
- Rebind the **data** belonging to a component

Adding/removing component dynamically is always a source of trouble and chances are that you can do it another way much simpler.

In your case, I would use a table that I bind to a list of String. Within each cell of the table, I render an input text box with the current String. There are three buttons, so there are three lists of String and three tables. Rough sketch for one button:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
   <h:column>
       <h:inputText value="#{item}"/>
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.cmd1}" value="cmd1" />
```

That's just the idea. You can use another component than a table that iterates on a list, or CSS, to customize the display and have the input boxes on one line.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in programmatic creation of UI with JSF, check this sample project:

[Dynamic Faces](http://confluence.highsource.org/x/FoBM)

In two words, you can use the binding attribute to bind a component instance to a property of a backing bean:

```
<h:panelGroup id="helloWorldPanel" binding="#{helloWorldBean.component}"/>
```

In the backing bean you can populate the bound component:

```
private UIComponent component;

public UIComponent getComponent() {
    return component;

}

public void setComponent(UIComponent component) {
        final UIOutput outputText = (UIOutput) facesContext.getApplication()
                .createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        outputText.setId("helloAnotherWorldMessage");
        component.getChildren().add(outputText);
        outputText.setValue("Hello, Another World!");
        this.component = component;
    }
```

However, it is not easy.

Comment: This way looks interesting.
And some suggestion how to group the textfields and buttons? Some panelGrid?

Comment: Yes, panel grid, panel group. Check the sample application, it has an example of dynamically built address editor.

Comment: Is this binding method only valid for JSF2? The `Dynamic Faces` link was for JSF2

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple forms in your view and group inputfields with the controling button. When the user click the button1, only data of inputfields 1,2,3 will be sent. idem for button2 and button3.

```
<f:view>
  <h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputText id="field1" value="#{backingBean.var1}"/>
    <h:inputText id="field2" value="#{backingBean.var2}"/>
    <h:inputText id="field3" value="#{backingBean.var3}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="SAVE" action="#{backingBean.doButton1}"/>
  </h:form>
  <h:form id="form2">
    <h:inputText id="field4" value="#{backingBean.var4}"/>
    <h:inputText id="field5" value="#{backingBean.var5}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="SAVE" action="#{backingBean.doButton2}"/>
  </h:form>
</f:view>
```